# Reciprocal of Hölder's inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, banach-spaces, holder-inequality

Let $(X,S,\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space, and $g \in M(X,S)$ such that $gs \in L_1(\mu)$ for any simple function $s \in L_p(\mu)$, with $p \in (1, \infty)$. Suppose $A \geq 0$ exists such that $|\int gs \mu| \leq A \|s\|_p$ for any function $s$. Prove:

$g \in L_q$ with $\dfrac{1}{p} + \dfrac{1}{q}=1$ and $\|g\|_q\leq A$

Comment: There is an answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3619580/reciprocal-of-holders-inequality?rq=1

Comment: You can also use : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3434325/if-fg-in-l-1-for-every-f-in-l-p-show-that-g-in-l-q?rq=1

Comment: Thank you, it helped me